# Angular code not being displayed correctly in browser

Tags: angular

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href = "#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage<span class = 'caret'></span></a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href = "#">Save Data</a></li>
                        <li> <a href = "#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Output only displays "Recipe Book" and the rest of the data is not being displayed... I am using Angular 8 and bootstrap.min.css has been added to angular.json file...

Comment: The collapse functionality uses jQuery and popper, have you added those?

Comment: share your code or make a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/) and why you put `containerr-fluid` inside `navbar`class